# Trying to input a blank for an input that requires 2 values separated by ", "

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

So I am trying to have the while loop end when inputting a blank for the input, but the problem is that the input takes 2 values separated by ", ". It is necessary for me to keep the input like that rather than separating them so how to fix this?

```
print(" Input the productIDs and quantities (input blank to complete transaction)")
    productID, quantity = input().split(", ")
    quantity = int(quantity)
    while quantity >= 1:
        self.addProductToTransaction(productID, quantity) 
    print("why u here bro u ain't buyin nothin")
```

When input is blank:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: Catch the exception (try-except) and exit if it raises.

Comment: On Python 3.10 plus match can do it on the results of the split. 1 case for add product another for exit.  https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/

Answer (score 0):

`while loop` should be outer, if you want to iteratively receive the input until a bad format is fed (handled by `try-except`).

```
while True:
    try:
        productID, quantity = input("Input the productIDs and quantities (input blank to complete transaction)").split(", ")
        quantity = int(quantity)
    except ValueError:
        print("why u here bro u ain't buyin nothin")
        break
    if quantity >= 1:
        self.addProductToTransaction(productID, quantity)
```

Comment: Or by using if!

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a execption handelling. Simply take as a string then split by `'`

```
print(" Input the productIDs and quantities (input blank to complete transaction)")
user_in = input()
if user_in !='':

    productID, quantity = user_in.split(',')
    print(quantity)
    quantity = int(quantity)
    while quantity >= 1:
        self.addProductToTransaction(productID, quantity) 
   
else:
    
    print("why u here bro u ain't buyin nothin")
```

Sample outs#

```
 Input the productIDs and quantities (input blank to complete transaction)

why u here bro u ain't buyin nothin
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to do this. Using `len()` or with `try..except` or with `if`

> if

```
while True:

    var = input("Input the productIDs and quantities (input blank to complete transaction)")
   
    if len(var) == ‘’: 

        print("why u here bro u ain't buyin nothin")
        break

    productID, quantity = Var.split(", ")



    quantity = int(quantity)
    if quantity >= 1:
        self.addProductToTransaction(productID, quantity)
```

> len()

```
while True:

    var = input("Input the productIDs and quantities (input blank to complete transaction)")
   
    if len(var) == 0: 

        print("why u here bro u ain't buyin nothin")
        break

    productID, quantity = Var.split(", ")



    quantity = int(quantity)
    if quantity >= 1:
        self.addProductToTransaction(productID, quantity)
```

> try…except

```
while True:

    try:


        productID, quantity = input("Input the productIDs and quantities (input blank to complete transaction)").split(", ")

        quantity = int(quantity)
        if quantity >= 1:
            self.addProductToTransaction(productID, quantity) 


    except ValueError:
    print("why u here bro u ain't buyin nothin")
    break
```

Three notes:

1. If you are printing a message for input the pass the string in the input function. And if you want user to input on next line, pass new line escape chat in the string `"Foo..string\n"`
2. I think  you are trying to have the loop that repeatedly ask the user the input then pass it to another class function `addProductToTransaction()`. Unless nothing is passed, in that case exit the loop. For that you can put the loop before input.
3. The solutions above are ordered per preference and performance (high to low)

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix it by using try/except.

```
print(" Input the productIDs and quantities (input blank to complete transaction)")
    try:
        productID, quantity = input().split(", ")
        quantity = int(quantity)
        while quantity >= 1:
            self.addProductToTransaction(productID, quantity) 
    except:
        print("why u here bro u ain't buyin nothin")
```

Comment: You should except only for ValueError to make sure you're not hiding any other Exceptions accidentally.